# What is the difference between heat transfer coeffiecient and thermal conductivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, condensed-matter

Can you also explain the two in plain words ?

Comment: Which definition do you use as [thermal conductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity#Definitions)? Does it differ from the [heat transfer coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient)? It can indeed happen that the two coincide, depending on the definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are confusingly similar. Heat transfer coefficient is given by:
$$
h = \frac{q}{\Delta T}
$$
where $q$ is heat flux. This corresponds to the ratio of heat flux to the temperature difference between two points.
Thermal conductivity is *often* given by:
$$
k = -\left|\frac{\mathbf{q}}{\nabla T}\right|
$$
i.e. the ratio between the heat flux vector, and the temperature gradient vector (I've assumed the material is isotropic here).
The difference is that $h$ is a property of an object or system, whereas $k$ is a property of material, the two can be easily related in 1D:
$$
h=kl
$$
where $l$ is the length of the object.

Comment: how do you find the lenght $l$ in $h=kl$? and can you suggest a book so that I can study this relation?

Comment: In one dimensional thermodynamics, it is simply the length of your object (normally envisaged as a rod or suchlike). You might like to consider something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Momentum-Heat-Mass-Transfer/dp/0470128682) for further reading.

Comment: Why is it $h=kl$ and not $k=hl$ and $k/l=h$? Because $k/l=h$ is what [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity#Other_quantities) gives. Also, the units would seem to suggest that it's $k/l=h$, as @mark jay had pointed out, and which is corroborated by wikipedia, which agrees that $h=W⋅K^{−1}⋅m^{−2}$ and $k=W⋅K^{−1}⋅m^{−1}$

Answer (score 0):

the heat transfer coefficient (*h*) is equal to the thermal conductivity (*k*) divided by the thickness of the object.
$$
h=\frac{k}{l}
$$
the units for *h* are $[W/m^2 K]$

the units for *k* are $[W/mK]$

Answer (score -1):

Thermal conductivity is applied in conduction of heat through media([Fourier's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier's_law))

Heat transfer coefficient is applied in convection of heat through a fluid ([Newton's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer#Newton's_law_of_cooling)).

Comment: It might be better to highlight (i.e., quote) the relevant section of the Wikipedia links into the post

Comment: Heat transfer coefficient applies for convection or conduction.